# Non-planar non-Hamiltonian chordal graphs with toughness greater than 1

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

The following article tells us that every planar chordal graph with toughness greater than 1 is Hamiltonian.

- Böhme T, Harant J, Tkáč M. More than one tough chordal planar graphs are Hamiltonian[J]. Journal of Graph Theory, 1999, 32(4): 405-410.

But this conclusion should be incorrect for non-planar chordal graphs. However, I don't know what the minimum-order example of such a graph is. How many vertices does it require at least?

- Let $G$ be a graph. **Toughness** of $G$  is  defined as
  $$
  t(G)= \min _S \frac{|S|}{c(G-S)}
  $$
  where $c$ is the number of connected components, and the minimum is taken over all separating set $S$ of $G$ (Chvátal 1973).
- A **chordal graph** is a simple graph in which every graph cycle of length four and greater has a cycle chord.

Comment: The graph which appears in Fig. 2 of the Chvátal paper you cite has $7$ vertices, is 1-tough, chordal, planar, and has no Hamiltonian cycle. The general construction appears in Theorem 3.3 of that paper, by taking $n=2$ you get a non-planar non-Hamiltonian $6/5$-tough chordal graph on 12 vertices.